# Generated gif has invalid header

Tags: c#, gif, photoshop

I am trying to generate a gif using **Bumpkit** gif encoder and while the gif works (Except for the first frames acting out), when I try to load the gif in photoshop, it says "Could not complete request because the file-format module cannot parse the file".

I don't know how to check the validity of the gif because it works when I view it. This is how Im using the Bumpkit library:

```
public void SaveImagesAsGif(Stream stream, ICollection<Bitmap> images, float fps, bool loop)
        {
            if (images == null || images.ToArray().Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("There are no images to add to animation");
            }

            int loopCount = 0;
            if (!loop)
            {
                loopCount = 1;
            }

            using (var encoder = new BumpKit.GifEncoder(stream, null, null, loopCount))
            {
                foreach (Bitmap bitmap in images)
                {
                    encoder.AddFrame(bitmap, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 / fps));
                }
            }
            stream.Position = 0;
        }
```

Am I doing something wrong when generating the gif?

Comment: Unless you want to actively get involved with this project, it is not one you ought to consider using.  The author gave up on it early.  https://github.com/DataDink/Bumpkit/issues/2

Comment: Thank you, I didnt see this but I guess you're right and I have to switch

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the Bumpkit gif encoder library, I think you have to call the InitHeader function first.

Take from the GifEncoder.cs source:

```
private void InitHeader(Stream sourceGif, int w, int h)
```

You can see the source code for the InitHeader function, the AddFrame function and the rest of the GifEncoder.cs file at https://github.com/DataDink/Bumpkit/blob/master/BumpKit/BumpKit/GifEncoder.cs

So it's a small edit to your code:

```
public void SaveImagesAsGif(Stream stream, ICollection<Bitmap> images, float fps, bool loop)
    {
        if (images == null || images.ToArray().Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("There are no images to add to animation");
        }

        int loopCount = 0;
        if (!loop)
        {
            loopCount = 1;
        }

        using (var encoder = new BumpKit.GifEncoder(stream, null, null, loopCount))
        {
            //calling initheader function
            //TODO: Change YOURGIFWIDTHHERE and YOURGIFHEIGHTHERE to desired width and height for gif
            encoder.InitHeader(stream, YOURGIFWIDTHHERE, YOURGIFHEIGHTHERE);

            foreach (Bitmap bitmap in images)
            {
                encoder.AddFrame(bitmap, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 / fps));
            }
        }
        stream.Position = 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is not a method that you can call from the encoder